# How to transpose an internal table rows into columns?

Tags: abap, transpose, internal-tables

I want to transpose my internal table rows into column and i want to fix the first column,i am trying to do it with the following code but i am not getting the expected result....it is not converting all the rows into columns

```
*Types Declaration
Types: BEGIN OF ty_t001w,
         ekorg TYPE t001w-ekorg,
         werks TYPE t001w-werks,
         name1 TYPE t001w-name1,
       END OF ty_t001w.

**Field Symbols Declaration
 FIELD-SYMBOLS:  <fs1> TYPE any,
                 <fs2> TYPE any.

**Internal table and work area declaration
 DATA: it1_col_row TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_t001w,
       wa1_col_row TYPE ty_t001w,
       it2_col_row TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_t001w,
       wa2_col_row TYPE ty_t001w,
       cline   TYPE sy-tabix.

**Filling internal table with data

Select *
  from t001w into corresponding fields of table it1_col_row
  where ekorg = p_ekorg
  and fabkl = p_fabkl.

**Looping Internal table to display data
 LOOP AT it1_col_row INTO wa1_col_row.
   WRITE: / wa1_col_row-ekorg, wa1_col_row-werks,wa1_col_row-name1.
 ENDLOOP.
 WRITE: /.

**Looping internal table to change rows into columns
 LOOP AT it1_col_row INTO wa1_col_row.
   CLEAR wa2_col_row.
   ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-tabix OF STRUCTURE wa2_col_row TO <fs1>.
   cline = sy-tabix.
   DO.
     ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index OF STRUCTURE wa1_col_row TO <fs2>.
     IF sy-subrc NE 0.
       EXIT.
     ENDIF.
     IF cline = 1.
       <fs1> = <fs2>.
       APPEND wa2_col_row TO it2_col_row.
     ELSE.
       READ TABLE it2_col_row INTO wa2_col_row INDEX sy-index.
       <fs1> = <fs2>.
       MODIFY it2_col_row FROM wa2_col_row INDEX sy-index.
     ENDIF.
   ENDDO.
 ENDLOOP.
*
**Looping internal table to display
 LOOP AT it2_col_row INTO wa2_col_row.
   WRITE: / wa2_col_row-ekorg,wa2_col_row-werks, wa2_col_row-name1.
 ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the field types of your `ty_t001w` have different length:

- `ekorg TYPE t001w-ekorg` has `CHAR 4`
- `werks TYPE t001w-werks` has also `CHAR 4`, but
- `name1 TYPE t001w-name1` has `CHAR 30`

You are using this same type `ty_t001w` for your source table (`it1_col_row`) as well as your target table (`it2_col_row`). So when you are mapping your **source rows table** to the **target columns table** then the 30 character field `name1` is mapped to the 4 character field `ekorg`. When I executed your program in my system I had the following output (dependent on the contents of my DB table `t001w`):

```
0001 0001 Werk 0001
0001 0002 Werk 0002
0001 0003 Werk 0003
0001 RAD1 Werk RAD1

0001 0001 0001
0001 0002 RAD1
Werk Werk Werk RAD1
```

At first glance this looks like "it is not converting all the rows into columns". But in the debugger I noticed that "Werk 0001" is actually **one** value, not two! However the value is truncated to only "Werk" because it is mapped from a 30 character field to the 4 character field. This happens to the bottom value of column 1 ("Werk 0002") and 2 ("Werk 0003"). The bottom value of column 3 ("Werk RAD1") is mapped correctly because here it's mapped from the 30 character field to the 30 character field.

To correct this issue I have created an extra `TYPES` definition `ty_t001w_col` for the target table `it2_col_row`. In this `TYPE` all fields have the maximum length of 30 characters ensuring no truncation may occur (see abap code below). It generates the following output:

```
0001 0001 Werk 0001
0001 0002 Werk 0002
0001 0003 Werk 0003
0001 RAD1 Werk RAD1

0001                           0001                           0001
0001                           0002                           RAD1
Werk 0001                      Werk 0002                      Werk RAD1
```

The corrected report:

```
REPORT zhd_stackoverflow_q27163908.

PERFORM function
      USING '0001'
            '01'.

FORM function
  USING p_ekorg TYPE ekorg
        p_fabkl TYPE fabkl.

Types Declaration
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_t001w,
         ekorg TYPE t001w-ekorg,
         werks TYPE t001w-werks,
         name1 TYPE t001w-name1,
       END OF ty_t001w.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_t001w_col,
         ekorg TYPE t001w-name1,
         werks TYPE t001w-name1,
         name1 TYPE t001w-name1,
       END OF ty_t001w_col.

*Field Symbols Declaration
 FIELD-SYMBOLS:  <fs1> TYPE any,
                 <fs2> TYPE any.

*Internal table and work area declaration
 DATA: it1_col_row TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_t001w,
       wa1_col_row TYPE ty_t001w,
       it2_col_row TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_t001w_col,
       wa2_col_row TYPE ty_t001w_col,
       cline   TYPE sy-tabix.

*Filling internal table with data

SELECT *
  FROM t001w INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it1_col_row
  WHERE ekorg = p_ekorg
  AND fabkl = p_fabkl.

*Looping Internal table to display data
 LOOP AT it1_col_row INTO wa1_col_row.
   WRITE: / wa1_col_row-ekorg, wa1_col_row-werks,wa1_col_row-name1.
 ENDLOOP.
 WRITE: /.

*Looping internal table to change rows into columns
 LOOP AT it1_col_row INTO wa1_col_row.
   CLEAR wa2_col_row.
   ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-tabix OF STRUCTURE wa2_col_row TO <fs1>.
   cline = sy-tabix.
   DO.
     ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index OF STRUCTURE wa1_col_row TO <fs2>.
     IF sy-subrc NE 0.
       EXIT.
     ENDIF.
     IF cline = 1.
       <fs1> = <fs2>.
       APPEND wa2_col_row TO it2_col_row.
     ELSE.
       READ TABLE it2_col_row INTO wa2_col_row INDEX sy-index.
       <fs1> = <fs2>.
       MODIFY it2_col_row FROM wa2_col_row INDEX sy-index.
     ENDIF.
   ENDDO.
 ENDLOOP.

*Looping internal table to display
 LOOP AT it2_col_row INTO wa2_col_row.
   WRITE: / wa2_col_row-ekorg,wa2_col_row-werks, wa2_col_row-name1.
 ENDLOOP.

 ENDFORM.
```