# Create internal table with column names and values from another tables column data in ABAP

Tags: sql, abap, opensql

I have a table which have fields like fieldname and fieldvalue. I am trying to turn this table into another format.

For example, I have below table with fields and values:

```
-----------------------------
|  Fieldname   | Fieldvalue |
-----------------------------
|   Matnr      |  001       |
|   Werks      | 1000       |
|   Statu      |   01       |
-----------------------------
```

I want to create a internal table with the following column names and values like this:

```
-------------------------------
|  Matnr  |  Werks  |  Statu  |
-------------------------------
   001       1000       01
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I see that you tagged your question [tag:opensql], how is your question related to OpenSQL? (I just see an ABAP question here)

Comment: Is the first table an internal table or a database table? And can you guarantee that each value for `Fieldname` will occur only once and map to a column of your second structure?

Comment: you want pivoting or transposing the itab, similar question already [were raised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163908/how-to-transpose-an-internal-table-rows-into-columns/27646386). This is natively not supported but there are multiple custom snippets that do this, e.g. [this one](http://zevolving.com/2013/11/abap-transpose-internal-table/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when fieldname = 'Matnr' then fieldvalue end) as matnr,
       max(case when fieldname = 'Werks' then fieldvalue end) as Werks,
       max(case when fieldname = 'Statu' then fieldvalue end) as Statu
from t;
```